# Glmertree options similar to partykit::mob

Tags: r, mixed-models, party

In the function call to glmertree, is there a way to get specify a minimum sample size for the terminal nodes? I have a relatively large sample (~7000) and would like to grow the tree to at least a depth where terminal nodes have about ~100 in each node. In partykit::mob and glmtree, there's the mob.control argument, but that doesn't seem to be available in glmertree. What are other options to achieve similar functionality?

Comment: could you provide us with a *small* [mcve] to play with?

Comment: There are sample data here in the vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmertree/vignettes/glmertree.pdf. However, after rereading the help page, I realized I was using the wrong argument within glmertree. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you please clarify?  Does `minsize = 100` as in my answer actually work?  (Pointing to the vignette is better than nothing, but it's nice to make it as convenient as possible for people to answer, by providing everything they need for an example without making them dig through the vignettes ...)

Comment: Ben, I think that your answer is perfectly fine. I have upvoted it and recommended in a separate comment that @stats134711 should accept it.

Comment: Yes, it's as simple as putting `minsize = 100` in the function call. In `mob` you have to use `mob.control=list(minsize=100,...,)`, which made me think that it was all being controlled via that argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but it seems like setting `minsize = 100` should work. `?glmertree`  says that the `...` argument corresponds to

> Additional arguments to be passed to ‘lmtree()’ or ‘glmtree()’.  See ‘mob_control’ documentation for details.

whereas `?mob_control` has

> minsize, minsplit, minbucket: integer. The minimum number of
> observations in a node.  If ‘NULL’, the default is to use 10
> times the number of parameters to be estimated (divided by
> the number of responses per observation if that is greater
> than 1). ‘minsize’ is the recommended name and
> ‘minsplit’/‘minbucket’ are only included for backward
> compatibility with previous versions of ‘mob’ and
> compatibility with ‘ctree’, respectively.

(more specifically, `glmtree()` has `...` arguments which in turn get passed to `mob_control()`)

---

Achim Zeileis points out that, using the data from the vignette,

```r
glmertree(depression_bin ~ treatment | cluster | age + anxiety + duration, data = DepressionDemo, minsize = 20)
```

gives different answers from the same model with `minsize = 50` (proving that the `minsize` argument does *something*, and presumably it does what is documented ...)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did try that, but that is not an argument that was passed down to glmertree. I looked into the documentation as well and couldn't find anything to set the size.

Comment: I checked the code and also tried an example. The advice by @BenBolker is correct and I think it would be good to accept it (by clicking on the check mark on the left of the answer). The example I tried is from the manual page, check out: `glmertree(depression_bin ~ treatment | cluster | age + anxiety + duration, data = DepressionDemo, minsize = 20)` vs. `minsize = 50`. This yields different trees due to the sample size restriction.